# Crediting Stack Overflow or Exchange posts

Tags: discussion, attribution, citation

Suppose I have a text with several references to Stack Overflow discussions. What would be the proper way to give credit to the authors of those posts without polluting the main text? Has anyone had any experience doing this?

Comment: Credit to Jon Skeet?

Comment: Credit them where? In what medium?

Comment: The CC-Wiki link at the bottom of each page, also had a guide for attributing: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Comment: I found this question (and answer): [Citing Stack Overflow discussions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49760)

Comment: @Oded: Credit them in a scientific textbook.

Comment: How do you cite any web resource in a scientific textbook? Normally in end notes - put the URL, date accessed and the author name/s.

Comment: Everyone: SO and SE, although somewhat "peer reviewed" is not an official source of knowledge. I, as the writer, have to do a lot of checking and provide an educated guess of what may be happening, though in a way "inspired" in SO. It's *not* a scientific publication, it has no status like that, and that makes the issue tricky.

Comment: @Oded: This is not the same. SO is not a scientific source under any circumstance (see here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37707/136844, for a similar opinion). See answer above, this is quite an interesting philosophical discussion: is SO of sufficient quality to be considered for scientific citation. To me, the answer is no, but it'll be interesting to discuss.

Comment: And yet, when you cite a resource, it is still a resource. Nothing is stopping you from adding a disclaimer about SO specific resources.

Comment: Resources are different: software is a resource I may cite, benchmarkings, real results. Answers and questions in SO are not a resource insofar as there are, e.g., multiple answers. Ideas are a dime a dozen, you don't cite ideas, you cite results.

Comment: Is there a place we can move this conversation?

Comment: @Oded: Notice, as well, that the names of authors are nicks, not real names, this is *really* not how you do it in scientific pubs. Is Oded your real name? :)

Comment: @DervinThunk [Purdue university disagrees](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/10/): from the citation guidance on online forums, "*If the author's name is not available, provide the screen name.*" If you are worried that your citation will not look authoritative without a real name, I think you should be considerably more concerned that your citation comes from a website that is publicly written and edited. Perhaps you could post a new question -- with substantially more detail about what SE question/site and what type of publication --  on http://academia.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DervinThunk You might also clarify your citation style (APA?), and explain *why* you want to cite SE. If you are writing about online behaviors on Q&A sites or you want to cite a subjective answer as anecdotal evidence that some particular viewpoint exists, then that's fine, and I don't see why you need worry that such a citation doesn't have a real name. If an answer helped point you to a reputable official resource, you might include a thank-you in your acknowledgements. If you gained non-subjective knowledge *entirely* from an SE answer, I would first verify it with a credible source.

Comment: @apsillers: Ok, I don't know why it's so complicated, I tend to write in sources everytime I can, but it sometimes become too much. Maybe i could provide an accompanying website or something like that. Should I cite you for this? :)

Comment: @DervinThunk whether or not it is appropriate in publication - I'm not in a position to judge, I was never in a position to need to write a paper that needed to cite online resources in this manner.  I'll leave the approprtiateness of it to you, but the simple answer is everything here is CC-Wiki, so you must attribute it by linking to the post, linking to the poster's profile, stating that is came from Stack Overflow.  If you hit those bullets, then you satisfy the license and the how is up to you.

Comment: @psubsee2003: What if a question about C inspires me to write an exercise? Should I give credit to the question owner? It's not that simple, unfortunately, :(